# Partitioning using multiple fields and getting the same group number per partitioned group

Tags: mysql, rank, partition, row-number

I have a data set that looks like below:

| CarType | Date | Car |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Honda | 5/28/2022 | car1 |
| Honda | 5/28/2022 | car1 |
| Honda | 8/11/2022 | car2 |
| Honda | 8/11/2022 | car2 |
| BMW | 5/28/2022 | car1 |
| BMW | 5/28/2022 | car1 |
| BMW | 8/11/2022 | car2 |
| BMW | 8/11/2022 | car2 |

I want to using row_number(), rank() function create an additional column 'Expected' that looks like this:

| CarType | Date | Car | Expected |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Honda | 5/28/2022 | car1 | 1 |
| Honda | 5/28/2022 | car1 | 1 |
| Honda | 8/11/2022 | car2 | 2 |
| Honda | 8/11/2022 | car2 | 2 |
| BMW | 5/28/2022 | car1 | 1 |
| BMW | 5/28/2022 | car1 | 1 |
| BMW | 8/11/2022 | car2 | 2 |
| BMW | 8/11/2022 | car2 | 2 |

I tried a query below. But does not seem to give me the right results

`select CarType, Date, Car,`
`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CarType, Car ORDER BY Date ASC) AS RW from table`

Comment: please rearrange your question it is not clear, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT CarType, 
       Date, 
       Car, 
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CarType 
                          ORDER BY Car) AS RW 
from table
```